# MySQL SELECT query as a prepared statement loops out no data from db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Been hitting my head all day here. My first experience at trying to prevent SQL Injection in code so I'm using a prepared statement and when I loop the result, my output is blank, but since it's a table all of the cells are there, just no data.
My code: 
    include_once("../includes/connect.php");

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `boards` WHERE `team_id` = ? ORDER BY name ASC";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $board);
$stmt->execute();



echo "<table border='1' class='table table-bordered'>

<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>In/Out</th>
<th>Note</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))

{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['inout'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
 //for troubleshooting
var_dump($stmt)
```

And here is what this looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1kKg.png

Any ideas why the data isn't filling in? any help is greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: You need to specify what you are binding , i.e., `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind all columns before calling `mysqli_stmt_fetch` as pointed in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $inout, $note);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $inout . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $note . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response vinodadhikary: When I try your advice I'm getting 'PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement'

Comment: @user2655005, you need to bind all the columns that will get returned by your query.  I just showed you those columns based on the values you were printing.

Comment: Got it, you were correct, I had more table values that I needed to return due to the *. Thank you!